# How to check carousel (bxslider) if active then destroy the first before initializing a new one

Tags: jquery, carousel, bxslider

I'm using a sort of carousel (bxslider) from here http://bxslider.com/

I got problem if I call the slider again. The behavior of sliding the images is weird. Sometimes it moves forward sometime backward. But if it is called only once the behavior is okay. Below is my html and script. I also provided jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jobzky/YXawY/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
var slider=$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true
});
slider.destroySlider();
slider.startAuto();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reload the slider like this:

```
slider.reloadSlider();
```

You can also add new options in when reloading it. [See the documentation for more info](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider).

In my case, that didn't do the job. I needed the slider to load different options responsively based on screen width. Not the cleanest or most elegant solution but here's what I did:

```
var slider = { };
var sliderActive = false;
var sliderSize = " ";

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 740 && sliderSize != 'large') {
        if(sliderActive === true) {
            slider.reloadSlider({
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 2,
                slideWidth: 570,
                slideMargin: 30,
                controls: true,
                pager: false,
                moveSlides: 1,
                auto: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    sliderSize = 'large';
                }
            });
        } else if(sliderActive === false) {
            slider = $(".bxslider").bxSlider({
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 2,
                slideWidth: 570,
                slideMargin: 30,
                controls: true,
                pager: false,
                moveSlides: 1,
                auto: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    sliderActive = true;
                    sliderSize = 'large';
                }
            });
        } 
    } else if($(window).width() <= 740 && sliderSize != 'small') {
        if(sliderActive === true) {
            slider.reloadSlider({
                controls: true,
                pager: false,
                auto: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    sliderSize = 'small';
                }
            });
        } else if(sliderActive === false) {
            sliderActive = true;
            slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                controls: true,
                pager: false,
                auto: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    sliderActive = true;
                    sliderSize = 'small';
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

// Call window resize to fire the function on document ready
$(window).resize();
```

The breakpoint is 740px. The code is pretty bloated since you need to include your options twice for both reloadSlider() and bxSlider(). I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: you can stay DRY by defining a variable that holds bxSlider options: `var bxSliderOptions = {
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 2,
                slideWidth: 570,
                slideMargin: 30,
                controls: true,
                pager: false,
                moveSlides: 1,
                auto: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    sliderActive = true;
                    sliderSize = 'large';
                }
            }; 
$(".bxslider").bxSlider(bxSliderOptions);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it this way. Basically, it checks if the parent of the slider has the bx-viewport class to make sure the bxslider is loaded before to destroy it.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var slider=$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true
});
if (slider.parent().hasClass('bx-viewport')){
    slider.destroySlider();
    slider.startAuto();
}
```